# How to analyze the value returned by the mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() in Android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, noise

I am building an android application that should start recording the audio when the recorded sound is above a certain threshold.

I researched and found out that the method getMaxAmplitude() of the MediaRecorder class gives an estimate of the loudness of the noise as a measure of sound pressure. It returns a value between 0 to +32767.

Here is the code that I have written.

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
while(True){
   if (mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() > THRESHOLD)
      System.out.println("Recording sound");
   else
      System.out.println("Sound recording not above the threshold level);
}
```

I have trouble figuring out the THRESHOLD value since there is no standard unit for the value returned by the getMaxAmplitude() function. It would be preferred if someone could suggest a conversion from the value returned by the getMaxAmplitude() function to decibel (dB) or any other useful unit.

Comment: Even I am trying to find an answer to this question. If I come up with one, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way in which you could interpret the output of `getMaxAmplitude()` as it will just give you the maximum value your phone's specific hardware is getting. Unfortunately the fact that a manufacturer complies with Android OS requirements doesn't ensure that you'll get the same response from every microphone. As a matter of fact not even all the devices from the same manufacturer have the same kind of microphone and thus you won't get the same frequency response or sensibility. If you want to convert to dB from this adimentional (but hardware dependent sound intensity proportional) units `getMaxAmplitude()` is returning, just use `dB = 20log10(getMaxAmplitude())`. Now if you want this to work on a wide range of devices I would advice you to include a calibration stage in your app so you can set a dynamic device dependent threshold instead of an absolute value. Maybe you can set your threshold as the relationship between the intensity you get when you calibrate and the intensity you get on the moment you're trying to capture. I don't know the specifics of your app but if I were you I would have at least one of these two things in mind to compare with. The moment when the microphone input is most quite and when it's most saturated (maybe you can generate your own loud sound from the speaker and record it)

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. I am thinking of doing the calibration this way, use the phone's microphone to record the sound in a quite environment and then use the phone to record a sound produced from the phone's speaker. I wonder how an application like Sound Meter is made, or if there is an API that Sound Meter provides to use their calculated decibel values.

Comment: If this is answer is good for you, please mark it as accepted so everyone would know this was the way to solve the problem. I don't know how Sound Meter Apps are made or if they provide an API for others to use. Please do some search about it and if you don't find the answer, please post another question so we could both find out

Comment: I would want to mark this answer as correct, but I have not been able to solve the problem completely using this. I did some analysis and the formula specified in the question calculates the decibel value as 60 compared to somewhere around 45 calculated by an app like Sound Meter. I would still like others to answer and do my own research before marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer has provided me with sufficient information to solve the given problem. Thanks